# What blogs report on e-commerce UI / UX?

Tags: resources, e-commerce

Ecommerce is a innovative sector in the areas of service, social media, and form design.  I wonder specifically: what blogs are following & reporting trends in commerce & online commerce?

Answer (score 1):

e-marketer blog is good - http://www.emarketer.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Get Elastic has some great content and a strong focus on e-commerce UX. [www.getelastic.com](http://www.getelastic.com/)